# small radio transmitter

Tags: radio, transmitter

I am trying to add a radio transmitter to small remote controlled airplane. I would like it to fit inside and the space I have to work with is 1.25 by 1.25 by 0.2 cm. I am wondering what sorts of issues I might run into with this, in particular regarding the size of the space for the transmitter.

Also, are there transmitters (not receivers) of this size that can be purchased online? If so where?

Thanks for the advice, addressing any other issues I might encounter would be appreciated.

The range should be about 300 meters
I am transmitting data about the planes propeller frequency.

Comment: What are you hoping to transmit? Over what kind of range?

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Be sure to take the tour to get the most out of this site:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 2):

I would investigate using an RFM12 (or RFM69 high-power) wireless module. They are quite small and inexpensive. I would try to simply send the AC "tachometer" signal from your propeller via the transmitter so you don't need any processing, etc. on board the plane.